# I created a file using "django-admin startproject <filename>", but can't find it on my system

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I used the following commands in this process--
pip install virtualenv
cd desktop
virtualenv env
env\Scripts\activate
pip install django
django-admin startproject

But i cant find the file on my desktop even though it got created successfully.

Comment: Did you give your project a name? if not, try: django-admin startproject my_project_name. source: https://www.w3schools.com/django/django_create_project.php

Answer (score 1):

install virtual environment using the command : `python -m pip install virtualenv` or `python3 -m pip install virtualenv`

now change to the location you want to set up virtual environment in. (in your question it is desktop) so use the command : `cd Desktop`

after that to set up virtual environment with the name "env" use the command :
`python -m venv env` or `python3 -m venv env` (according to your python version).

now use the command `source ./env/bin/activate` - in linux.
or use the command `env\Scripts\activate` - on windows.

now install django `python -m pip install django` or use `python3` instead of `python` in the command.(according to the python version).

next create your django project : `django-admin startproject <projectname>`.
at the position of  give your project name. example "django-1".

now you could see the project there with the name "django-1".